# How do I include class from .jar in Jacoco coverage report?

Tags: ant, jacoco

I'm having an ant script which builds, runs JUnit tests, creates reports and creates coverage report about a couple of selected classes which are in a specific package. I have now instead created a library (.jar) containing the class I want to the coverage report to "focus on". I know how I can include which specific files to include in the coverage report given packages etc, how can I do this for the class in my .jar file? The current ant task for the coverage:

```
<target name="report" depends="junit">
    <jacoco:report xmlns:jacoco="antlib:org.jacoco.ant">                     
        <executiondata>
            <file file="JacocoFile"/>
        </executiondata>                       
         <structure name="Example Project">
           <classfiles>
                   <!-- Right now, everything is in the extotest package -->
            <fileset dir="${build.dir}/extotest"> 
                    <include name="*.class"/>    
            </fileset>
           </classfiles>
           <sourcefiles encoding="UTF-8">
             <fileset dir="${src.dir}/extotest">
             </fileset>
             <fileset dir="${src.dir}/test">
             </fileset>
           </sourcefiles>
         </structure>

        <html destdir="${coverage}/webcoverage"/>
        <xml destfile="${coverage}/coverage.xml" /> 

    </jacoco:report>
   </target>
```

Ciao!

Answer (score 1):

Copy your jar files to directory path which you have given in the ant task.
Jacoco ant task will take care.
I have tried the same and i found success in that.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add a jar file to the classfiles for your coverage report,instead of providing the dir attribute for fileset tag, you must provide the file attribute

eg. instead of using

```
<fileset dir="${build.dir}/extotest">   
      <include name="*.jar"/> 
</fileset>
```

as mentioned in the above answer, use

```
<fileset file="${build.dir}/extotest/*.jar" />
```

Check if this solves the problem

Answer (score -1):

Add

```
<fileset dir="${build.dir}/extotest"> 
      <include name="*.class"/>    
      <include name="*.jar"/> 
</fileset>
```

in the ANT Script and add the jar files to the class path.

Comment: When added jar file .. Jacoco throws error while generating report.